# Issue with the createSharedElementStackNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am having an issue with the CreateSharedElementStacknavigator that it doesn't transition back to the initial spot where I left off if I were to use a scroll view. For example, Like if I were to scroll down a couple swipes at the home page and click on an item. It would direct me to another screen. Now if I were to press another Item inside that screen, then it will direct me to another screen once more. Okay, let's say if I wanted to return back to the home screen and I click the back button on the screen I am in and hit the back button again to return to home. Now, it leaves me at the top of the screen instead of the initial point where I left off at the middle. Anyway I can get this fixed?

I have tried using the `createNativeStackNavigator` and it does leave me back at the initial point where I left off if I were to jump two screens more in an item.

I want to keep the `createSharedElementStackNavigator` because of the fluid animation it contains, but also have the `createNativeStackNavigator` which helps to keep the initial screen not transition to the top.

Here's a video example of what I am talking about:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ugv0z6vUD5XZjt52hHE3OqBD0PVjfrX2/view?usp=sharing